# How exactly do you use React-Router-Dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to use `react-router-dom` and I am having difficulties, even after spending almost 1 hour on it.

I have checked the docs from reacttraining, but I am ashamed to say I still do not grasp the concept.

One of the confusing aspects is the fact that there is `BrowserRouter`, `Route`, `Link`, `Switch`. So many of them, what does each one do? Plus you have to wrap some code in `Route`, some other code in `Switch` and so on. It is all so confusing.

This is the code I already have:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import AddPlayer from "./Components/AddPlayer";
import DisplayPlayers from "./Components/DisplayPlayers";
import EditPlayer from "./Components/EditPlayer";
import FilteredPlayers from "./Components/FilteredPlayers";

const App = () => {
  const [showAll, setShowAll] = useState(true);
  const [filteredText, setFilteredText] = useState("");
  const [editing, setEditing] = useState(false);
  const [playerToEdit, setPlayerToEdit] = useState();
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState([
    { id: 1, name: "Cristiano Ronaldo", club: "Juventus", important: true },
    { id: 2, name: "Lionel Messi", club: "Barcelona", important: false },
    { id: 3, name: "Kaka", club: "AC Milan", important: true },
    { id: 4, name: "Ronaldinho", club: "Barcelona", important: true },
    { id: 5, name: "Deco", club: "Barcelona", important: false },
    { id: 6, name: "Sergio Aguero", club: "Manchester City", important: false },
    { id: 7, name: "Frank Lampard", club: "Chelsea", important: true },
    {
      id: 8,
      name: "Son Heung Min",
      club: "Tottenham Hotspur",
      important: true
    },
    {
      id: 9,
      name: "Michael Carrick",
      club: "Manchester United",
      important: false
    },
    { id: 10, name: "Paolo Dybala", club: "Juventus", important: false }
  ]);

  const addPlayer = obj => {
    obj.id = players.length + 1;
    const temp = [...players, obj];
    setPlayers(temp);
  };

  const deletePlayer = id => {
    let i = 0;
    const temp = [...players];

    temp.forEach((el, a) => {
      if (el.id === id) i = a;
    });

    temp.splice(i, 1);
    setPlayers(temp);
  };

  const whichPlayer = obj => {
    setEditing(true);
    setPlayerToEdit(obj);
  };

  const editPlayer = (id, obj) => {
    const temp = [...players];
    setPlayers(temp.map(player => (player.id === id ? obj : player)));
    setEditing(false);
  };

  const toggle = id => {
    let i = 0;
    const temp = [...players];

    temp.forEach((el, a) => {
      if (el.id === id) i = a;
    });

    temp[i].important = !temp[i].important;
    setPlayers(temp);
  };

  let toShow = showAll ? players : players.filter(player => player.important);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header>Soccer database</header>
      <h2>Filter by name</h2>
      <input
        placeholder="Filter by name"
        onChange={e => setFilteredText(e.target.value)}
        value={filteredText}
      />
      <button onClick={() => setFilteredText("")}>Clear filter</button>
      {editing ? (
        <EditPlayer
          editPlayer={editPlayer}
          setEditing={setEditing}
          playerToEdit={playerToEdit}
          setFilteredText={setFilteredText}
        />
      ) : (
        <AddPlayer addPlayer={addPlayer} />
      )}
      {filteredText.length > 0 ? (
        <FilteredPlayers
          toShow={toShow}
          filteredText={filteredText}
          whichPlayer={whichPlayer}
          deletePlayer={deletePlayer}
          setShowAll={setShowAll}
          showAll={showAll}
          toggle={toggle}
        />
      ) : (
        <DisplayPlayers
          whichPlayer={whichPlayer}
          deletePlayer={deletePlayer}
          toShow={toShow}
          setShowAll={setShowAll}
          showAll={showAll}
          toggle={toggle}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

As you can see, the return section of `App` is already crowded, how and where am I supposed to put all the `react-router` stuff? Basically what my app does is it displays a table, with each row representing each soccer player. I want to be able to click on a name, and go to a separate component that displays more information regarding that specific player. If you need the rest of the code to assist me, please let me know.

Thank you everyone for your time!

Answer (score 0):

See.. Avoid using the unnessary state variables and new components.. we don't actually need to store anything, anywhere. It just makes your code messy.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-routing-rcef9

Now coming to the react-router. I think documentation is pretty elaborate. Give yourself another try. You should be fine.

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say I am a junior level, I don't quite understand your code.

May I ask why my states are unnecessary?

Comment: excuse me.. i didn't mean to sound like that.. what i am saying, we could do this with less components and varibles.

Comment: And.. please let me know.. which one in specific, you would like me to explain.

Comment: I would like to keep my current code, but to be able to click, for example, Cristiano Ronaldo, and bring a new component exactly like yours - With Cristiano Ronaldo at the top, and Juventus at the bottom. That is all I want. I just dont know where to wrap <BrowserRouter>, <Route>, etc.

Comment: then.. you better share your whole code.. including all components.. how about in https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Comment: Alright, here is the link.
https://codesandbox.io/s/Friendly-clarke-qudv2
 I will go to sleep now. I will respond tomorrow. Thanks Barun!

Comment: @5ecured i have added a new answer.. Did you get a chance to go throgh it..

Answer (score 0):

`react-router-dom` is the simplest ever. You don't need to use any if condition.

The parent in this package is `<BrowserRouter>` inside this we mention our routes like this -->>

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
    <BrowserRouter>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
    </BrowserRouter>
```

But, What if user put any wrong url then? Obviously it will throw error and your app crashed. So you need to put the conditions on the route. Despite this, you can use `Switch` like below ->>

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
   <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
            <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

and in the component named `NotFound` you can have code like this ->>

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const NotFound = () => (
    <div className='NotFound' >
        <h3> Sorry, page not found!</h3>
        <Link to='/'> Back to home </Link>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: In this code, You can see the examples of all imported object from ```react-router-dom``` i.e. BrowserRouter, Route, Switch and Link.

Answer (score 0):

ok.. so i have managed to implement the Routing as you needed. I have made this with few changes, as best as possible.

I have also fixed a couple of console errors along the way.

Detailed explanations coming up soon.

**Edit:**

1. First i have enclosed the root component(i.e. `<App />`)
   `<BrowserRouter>
      <App />
   </BrowserRouter>`
2. Then I have added a new component(`<PlayerDetails player />`) which only 
   takes the player as argument and renders it.
3. In ViewPlayer and FilterPlayer components, I have bound the onclick event
   to the name columns in the table.
   `<td style={style} onClick={() => history.push("/" + player.id)}>`
4. Now I could have used some Routes here, but I haven't used any. because its 
   not really needed here. Because we are only rendering one component, just 
   with a conditional playerId in URL.

   So here I am fetching the playerId from URL, if exists.
   `const { pathname } = useLocation();
    const playerId = pathname.replace("/", "");`
5. If playerId is shown in URL, I am rendering PlayerDetails component, or else 
   the regular App component will be rendered.

   Hope i was able to explain. Let me know if you have any doubts.

https://codesandbox.io/s/crud-players-11hdi

Comment: Thanks Barun, I appreciate your help. I found another way that for me is a bit easier to understand because my level is junior. But thank you again for your help